# can we check if the OpenAPI spec file is in sync with code written?

Tags: continuous-integration, swagger, protocol-buffers, openapi, proto

I have some repos for which I want to enable the OpenAPI(Previously known as Swagger) spec file check. There are tools(i.e. [Stoplite's Spectral](https://stoplight.io/open-source/spectral/)) available for the validation of file which provides lint support for the Yaml file.

However, what I want to achieve is that if I write an API in the code (i.e. GO or Java or Python) and if I do not specify that API in the OpenAPI Spec file, then it should throw an error in the CI tool.

If we can check the sync between Protocol buffer and OpenAPI spec file then also it would be useful so please do mention if any tool is available.

I believe that we may require different tools for different languages which are okay, but do we have that in any of the languages or not that I am not sure of.

Comment: It would be helpful if we can check OpenAPI spec against Protocol buffer and see if it's in sync or not.